# New PayPal Sandbox - crazy things

Tags: paypal

Paypal'guys changed something. Before the new interface, what I did in order to test my IPN server was:

1. Go to sandbox.paypal.com and Login
2. Create Test Account (Personal and Business)
3. Enter sandbox.paypal.com to set the IPN url in Profile.

Now, I create 2) by going to developer.paypal.com. BUT: when I go to Sandbox Site and click on Profile, I am redirected AGAIN to a page saying "You must login". I click on the url and I am redirect AGAIN to developer.paypal.com where I am already logged in.
CRAZY!The question is: has anybody the same problem? Can someone help me to understand what Paypal'guys changed?

Comment: how is this a question?

Comment: Sorry, the question was implicit: is there anybody can help with this problem?

Comment: +1 Maybe so but Google brought me here and its helped no end. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yeah there were some very recent major product launches, which included a new developer site.  In order to get to the IPN simulator, just do this:

1. Go to http://developer.paypal.com and log in with your paypal.com credentials, not your sandbox credentials
2. Once logged in, go to the "Applications" tab, and then the "IPN Simulator" will be listed on the left hand menu.

Let me know if you run into any issues,

Jon

Comment: The simulator is ok. I can use it and test it. The problem arises when I want to customize the Test accounts in order to use the IPN service (which is the same procedure I do for live account). When I click (in developer.paypal.com) Test account-><MyTestccount>->Sandbox site, I cannot enter or login: the web site says "You must login in Sandboxsite", but I am laready logged in!