# Enable IPN url in sandbox for seller (buisness) account

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I read on https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/ that

> Of course, you’ll need to make sure you’ve configured IPN in your
>   sandbox seller account just like you would a live account, too, so
>   that it functions as expected.

**So how to enable IPN url in sandbox seller (buisness) account?**
Could someone take a screenshot and show me. I just found IPN url in settings in live account.

I also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513624/new-paypal-sandbox-where-to-input-ipn-url-in-sandbox-test-site-ui) but there is no such thing under Profile link:

> Profile link and look for "Instant Payment Notification preferences"
>   Under the Sub-Heading "Selling preferences"

**Does Enabling IPN for live account would enable it automatically for sand box seller account ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a sandbox account it is treated like an entirely separate account.  Anything you need to configure in order for API calls to work will need to be configured separate on each account.

That said, sandbox accounts typically enable most of the APIs by default for ease of testing, while the live servers do require specific approval for use at times.

In this case, though, the IPN URL is a custom value you are setting, and again, it needs to configured in each account because they are entirely separate accounts from each other.

So, the same method you used to enable the IPN URL on your live PayPal would be used to enable it in your sandbox account.  It's just that you would log in to www.sandbox.paypal.com/home using your sandbox account instead of www.paypal.com.

They may look a little different if the PayPal account versions for each aren't exactly the same, but the overall process is the same.  Log in to the account, click into the profile, and find the Instant Payment Notification Preferences within your profile settings.  Then set it accordingly.